# Strange behavior of Angular date

Tags: angular, date

Can somebody explain why I have to set my date to `new Date(2020, 0, 25);`
Result: 'Sat **Jan** 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)'

I have another example

Variabele initialized to: `new Date(2019, 10, 25);`
Result: Mon **Nov** 25 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

Last time I checked my calender, Month 10 is still Oktober

Comment: Javascript counts months from 0, January is 0. December is 11.

Comment: Re: your first example, what _did_ you expect for month 0, if not January?

Comment: In that example I first set the date to (2020,  1, 25) after I saw thet the result was February, I changed it to (2020, 0, 25).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript uses zero based indexing for month, so you would have to use

```
new Date(2019, 9, 25)
```

for 25th Oct 2019